# Get the clicked items Firestore document id on ListView

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here I have written the code for accessing all the documents in the collection and show it in a ListView.

Here is the method for getting the data.

```
Future getData() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn =
    await firestore.collection("LiveProducts").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
}
```

Here is my build method.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 295,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: SpinKitCircle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              // title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["ProductName"]),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: onClick,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      height: 300,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(snapshot
                              .data[index].data["ProductImageLink"]),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        // name,
                                        snapshot.data[index]
                                            .data["ProductName"],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 30,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        // type,
                                        // '',
                                        snapshot.data[index]
                                            .data["ProductCompany"],
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
  void onClick() {
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
   return PlacingBids();
  }));
}
```

I have listed all of of the documents in a ListView but I am facing an issue. I need to get the Firestore id of the clicked document on the ListView. How can I do it?

Comment: What does `getData()` returns?

Comment: It returns all the documents

Comment: You have provided the code already, sorry I missed that part.

Comment: It's Okay is there any solution

Comment: I'm writing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) class have an `id` property which returns documents key.

You can wrap your list items with `GestureDedector` and pass the document id to the ònTap` callback.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("Item with key " +
                        snapshot.data[index].id +
                        " clicked.");
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["ProductName"]),
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            );
          }
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sir actually  print("Item with key " +
                        snapshot.data[index].id +
                        " clicked.");  this is not working  this is giving an error Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'id'.

Comment: Which version or package are you using for Firestore? `DocumentSnapshot` surely has an `id` field.

Comment: Its taking id without error but after clicking the button it is showing error

Comment: I/flutter (23359): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (23359): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (23359): Class 'DocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'id'.
I/flutter (23359): Receiver: Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (23359): Tried calling: id

Comment: Please delete the comments and add the full error stack on your question.

Comment: Actually i don't know how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207124/discussion-between-easeccy-and-divyanshu-bhaskar).

Comment: We haven't yet, you can join the chat and tell us your problem there.